# Is intptr_t a signed counterpart of uintptr_t (and vice versa)?

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming

I'm developing some tests for the add_signed MPL class that converts the type to its signed counterpart. It is defined as follows:

```
template<class T>
struct add_signed { 
    typedef T type;
};

template<>
struct add_signed<std::uint8_t> { 
    typedef std::int8_t type;
};

template<>
struct add_signed<std::uint16_t> { 
    typedef std::int16_t type;
};

template<>
struct add_signed<std::uint32_t> { 
    typedef std::int32_t type;
};

template<>
struct add_signed<std::uint64_t> { 
    typedef std::int64_t type;
};
```

While testing on different types I noticed that the following evaluates to true:

```
std::is_same<add_signed<uintptr_t>::type, intptr_t>::value  // true
```

Similarly for the add_unsigned MPL class, the following code evaluates to true:

```
std::is_same<add_unsigned<intptr_t>::type, uintptr_t>::value  // true
```

My compiler is MSVC 2010.

So the question is - can we assume that in all (sane) compilers signing intptr_t will produce uintptr_t and vice versa?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The types `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are optional in ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (C99), but where one is implemented, so is the other. All signed types have an unsigned counterpart of the same size, and vice versa.

> #### §7.18.1 Integer types
>
> When typedef names differing only in the absence or presence of the initial `u` are defined, they shall denote corresponding signed and unsigned types as described in 6.2.5; an implementation providing one of these corresponding types shall also provide the other.
>
> ...
>
> #### §7.18.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers
>
> The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid
>   pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void,
>   and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> ```
> intptr_t
> ```
>
> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid
>   pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void,
>   and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> ```
>  uintptr_t
> ```
>
> These types are optional.

Note that within the meaning of the C standard, functions are not objects; it is not guaranteed by the C standard that `uintptr_t` can hold a function pointer.

Fortunately, [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_12) steps to the rescue: it does require that object pointers and function pointers are the same size.

> #### 2.12.3 Pointer Types
>
> All function pointer types shall have the same representation as the type pointer to `void`. Conversion of a function pointer to `void *` shall not alter the representation. A `void *` value resulting from such a conversion can be converted back to the original function pointer type, using an explicit cast, without loss of information.
>
> Note:
>
> The ISO C standard does not require this, but it is required for POSIX conformance.