# Get memory address of Objective C object?

Tags: ios, nsobject

Is there any better way to get the memory address than this?

```
NSLog(@"%p", anObject);
```

I would rather get the plain long value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can caste some `Type*` to `intptr_t`, and look at this address in decimal representation:

```
NSLog(@"%lu", (uintptr_t)anObject);
```

To represent pointer address as integer in C exists 2 [types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10398594/1155948): `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`.

`intptr_t` is defined as `__darwin_intptr_t`.
and `__darwin_intptr_t` [defined as](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.24.17/bsd/ppc/_types.h.auto.html) `long`:

```
typedef long            __darwin_intptr_t;
```

`uintptr_t` defined as `unsigned long`:

```
typedef unsigned long           uintptr_t;
```

[I think what](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) for `uintptr_t` I should use `%lu` and for `intptr_t` I should use `%li`:

```
NSLog(@"%lu", (uintptr_t)anObject);
NSLog(@"%li", (intptr_t)anObject);
```

Comment: would you like to change your answer to:
NSLog(@"%lu", (intptr_t) anObject); ?  I just tested that successfully. %d produced a negative number with too few bits.

Comment: Also I think, that uintptr_t will be better type for this.